# How do I access a control from a detailsview programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, databound

I need to be able to modify controls from my detailsview programmatically on databind. Right now I'm using this code but I'm getting an "Index was out of range" error.

```
Private Sub dtlApplication_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtlApplication.DataBound
    Dim resumeLink As HyperLink = dtlApplication.Rows.Item(0).FindControl("lnkResume")
    resumeLink.NavigateUrl = "Resumes/"
End Sub
```

I also tried this but got an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
Private Sub dtlApplication_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtlApplication.DataBound
    Dim resumeLink As HyperLink = dtlApplication.FindControl("lnkResume")
    resumeLink.NavigateUrl = "Resumes/"
End Sub
```

I think the problem might be that the detailsview does not have any controls when the page initially loads since it doesn't get them until I select a row in my main gridview. Basically, I am trying to execute this code when I select a row in the gridview, not when the page initially loads. Could that be it? If so, where should I execute this code if not in the detailsview databound?

Here is the detailsview and corresponding datasource markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtlApplication" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false"
                        DataKeyNames="appID" DataSourceID="ds2" CellPadding="0" BorderColor="Transparent" 
                        BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="459" CssClass="dtlView">
                        <Fields>                                
                            <asp:TemplateField showheader="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>  

                                    <h3>Resume</h3>

                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkResume" Text="View Resume &raquo;"></asp:HyperLink>                                        

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                                
                        </Fields>
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" FirstPageText="&larr; First" LastPageText="Last &rarr;"
                            nextpagetext="Next &raquo;" previouspagetext="&laquo; Previous" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="paging" />
                    </asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cn %>" 
                         SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="sp_SelectApplicationDetail" 
                         EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="600">  
                         <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="appID" ControlID="gvAdmin" PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
                         </SelectParameters>         
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: could you post your detailsview markup?

Comment: I updated the question with the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailsview's datasource uses a gridview's selectedvalue as it's select control parameter, and upon page load the gridview does not have a selectedindex yet, so the detailsview is empty. I had to set the gridview's selectedindex on page load to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DataBound event is not a the best event for such issue. Try to use [ItemCreated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcreated.aspx) event handler instead. Like here, for example:

```
Private Sub dtlApplication_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtlApplication.ItemCreated

    Dim someRow As  DetailsViewRow = dtlApplication.Rows(0);
    If someRow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub       
    Dim link As HyperLink = DirectCast(someRow.FindControl("lnkResume"), HyperLink)

    If link Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    link.NavigateUrl = "Resumes/"
End
```

Comment: I tried that and still the same error. Could it be that the datasource for the detailsview uses my main gridview's selectedvalue to populate it?

Comment: It is possible, but I'm not sure that there will be nothing for resumeLink, actually. This is because it haven't explicit databinding.

Comment: I tried your code and I got this error on the first line: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index." This tells me that the dtlApplication does not have any rows upon ItemCreated event. Am I on the right track there?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no place where can be such exception except dtlApplication.Rows(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the detailsview visible property to false On page Load Event